# Foundation Joyride nub position

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I'm using [Foundation's Joyride plugin](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html) and I can't find the way to position the nub of the tooltip on the left side of it. Hope someone has solved it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nub's position can be set in the data-options attribute in the markup or passed in during initialization.

**data-options attribute** example:

```
<ol class="joyride-list" data-joyride>
    <li data-id="firstStop" data-text="Next" data-options="nub_position: left;">
        <p>nub_position: left;</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**during initialization** example:

```
// Set the default nub_position
$(document).foundation({
      joyride : {nub_position: 'left'}
});

// Start Joyride
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start');
```

You can find out more about configuring Joyride at:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html

  - There is a section called **Optional JavaScript Configuration** at the bottom of the page that will give you an overview of what can be configured.
  - Note that the documentation makes it look like it can be refereed to as **nubPosition**, but you actually have to use **nub_position**. You can check the variable names in the Joyride JavaScript file.
- http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

  - A general overview of how to use and configure the JavaScript used by Foundation such as how to set defaults during initialization.
- http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin

  - A great place to get started and to download a template that really shows off what joyride can do.
- http://cdpn.io/eKgIE

  - A CodePen I through together to test the nub positioning.

If you have any questions let me know.

Comment: I'm on Joyride 2.1 and it required me to use this syntax: data-options="tipLocation: top; nubPosition: bottom;"